# Better Addressbook dialog?

Tags: xpages

I am using the extension library addressbook dialog.  The search is pretty horrible for a large company like ours.  Is there a better addressbook dialog out there?  I'd like to avoid writing my own right now.

Comment: I'm using a typeahead edit box with some code and am quite happy with that.

Comment: Bruce - I have an address dialog custom control I developed for a non EXT library environment.  It was created specifically to mimic the Notes Client dialog.  If you're interested I can send you the code.  NOTE- it hasn't been tested in a large environment.

Comment: Not sure why the 5 guys below think that this question is vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. It makes perfect sense to me and probably everyone else who develops in Xpages. He is looking for an alternative to the current dialog box adaptation of the NAB Name picker. How hard is that to understand? I am also sure he is not the only one who would like to see an answer on this topic. I know I would.

Comment: You can look into [XPages Name Picker](http://www.openntf.org/Internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?databaseName=CN=NotesOSS2/O=NotesOSS!!Projects%5Cpmt.nsf&documentId=BB49635F04CB3924862575B1002D5F9C&action=openDocument) on OpenNTF. It is not like address book dialog in Notes instead more like Facebook style name picker. It may provide you with some ideas or a starting point.

Comment: Micheal,  I would very much like to see your db.  If I can only figure out how to PM you I would send you mey email. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bruce you might need to code it yourself. It seems development doesn't see a need for being mores creative or they feel enhanced dialogues are to specific. Check [this idea](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-7R56R6) for inspiration.

Comment: Inspired by Michael, I did end up writing my own.  I sowed it to one of the IBM developers at LotusSphere and it might actually get put into the extension lib or at least the basic design anyway.  I am sure someone a little more savy in Java could do a better job on the coding part but it works great.